# Tabulator 5.2 - 'Cannot remove event, no matching event found: cell-editing'

Tags: tabulator

After converting a project from tabulator 4.9 to 5.2 I have a warning being output to the console log, which I cannot resolve. I don't have any editing enabled on any cells.
Is there anything I can do to try and isolate what is causing the warning?

> Cannot remove event, no matching event found: cell-editing ƒ (){var e=arguments.length>0&&void 0!==arguments[0]&&arguments[0];return this.visible&&(this.blurable&&(document.body.removeEventListener("keydown",this.escEvent),document.body.removeEventListener("cl…

Comment: Coulld you include your working demo?

Comment: I am having this same issue. Can you show a code sample or have you found a solution for it?